# In R, How to highlight values of a specific column and export to existing xlsx file

Tags: r, xlsx, highlight, tibble

In `iris` tibble, How do I highlight the rows where `Petal.Width < 1.0` and export the output as a `worksheet/tab` of an  existing `xlsx` file

```
# tibble
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(broom)

set.seed(1234)

df <- iris[sample(nrow(iris), 20), ]
df
```

output

```
# tibble
 Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
28           5.2         3.5          1.5         0.2     setosa
80           5.7         2.6          3.5         1.0 versicolor
101          6.3         3.3          6.0         2.5  virginica
111          6.5         3.2          5.1         2.0  virginica
137          6.3         3.4          5.6         2.4  virginica
133          6.4         2.8          5.6         2.2  virginica
144          6.8         3.2          5.9         2.3  virginica
132          7.9         3.8          6.4         2.0  virginica
98           6.2         2.9          4.3         1.3 versicolor
103          7.1         3.0          5.9         2.1  virginica
90           5.5         2.5          4.0         1.3 versicolor
70           5.6         2.5          3.9         1.1 versicolor
79           6.0         2.9          4.5         1.5 versicolor
116          6.4         3.2          5.3         2.3  virginica
14           4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1     setosa
126          7.2         3.2          6.0         1.8  virginica
62           5.9         3.0          4.2         1.5 versicolor
4            4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa
143          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9  virginica
40           5.1         3.4          1.5         0.2     setosa
```

My attempt

please note: my attempt does not show highlighted rows in the `xlsx` file, so I am open to other approaches.

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(xlsx)

# with the below code, I am unable to export as an xlsx file because "kable" is not a dataframe
df_highlighted <- kable(df)%>%row_spec(which(df$`Petal.Width` < 1.0), color="red")
df_highlighted

# export the dataframe to an existing xlsx file
write.xlsx(df_highlighted, file="existing_file.xlsx", sheetName="df_highlighted", append=TRUE, row.names=FALSE)
```

Please comment and share your code. Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the `openxlsx` package. Here is an example:

```r
library(openxlsx)

set.seed(1234)

df <- iris[sample(nrow(iris), 20), ]

wb <- createWorkbook()

addWorksheet(wb, "iris")

writeData(wb, "iris", df)

highlight <- createStyle(fontColour = "#000000",
                         bgFill = "#FFFF00")

conditionalFormatting(wb,
                      "iris",
                      cols = 1:length(df),
                      rows = 1:nrow(df),
                      rule = "$D1<1",
                      style = highlight)

saveWorkbook(wb, "example.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for your attempt, I was wondering does `overwrite = TRUE` and `append =TRUE`  work interchangeably?

Comment: Does my code produce the output you were looking for? If so, please accept the answer. If not, please specify how my answer failed to meet your requirements.

`append` and `overwrite` are arguments for separate functions. They do different things. 

The `append` argument to `xlsx::write.xlsx()` defines whether your table should be added to an existing workbook as a new sheet. The `overwrite` argument to `openxlsx::saveWorkbook()` as in my example defines whether the function should replace "example.xlsx" if it already exists on disk.